# Adding class to existing class using dojo when custom sort is applied on enhanced grid view

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

Created a dojo enhanced Grid, with custom sorting. How to add sort arrows(up/down) to existing classes with code and not using css.

```js
var mygrid = new EnhancedGrid({
    id: "grid",
    store: gridStore,
    structure: gridStructure, 
    canSort : function(index){
        alert(index);
    }
}, dojo.byId("mydatagrid"))
```

I have tried using create, place, domclass in dojo. But it is working as expected.

```css
<div hidefocus="hidefocus" role="grid" dojoattachevent="onmouseout:_mouseOut" tabindex="0" aria-multiselectable="true" class="dojoxGrid" id="grid" widgetid="grid" style="width: 680px; height: auto; -moz-user-select: none;" aria-readonly="true" align="left">
 <div class="dojoxGridMasterHeader" dojoattachpoint="viewsHeaderNode" role="presentation" style="display: block; height: 24px;"><div class="dojoxGridHeader" dojoattachpoint="headerNode" role="presentation" style="width: 679px; left: 1px; top: 0px;">
  <div dojoattachpoint="headerNodeContainer" style="width:9000em" role="presentation">
   <div dojoattachpoint="headerContentNode" role="row"><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="gridHdr0" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem" idx="0" style="width:200px;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode">COLUMNVALUE</div></th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="gridHdr1" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem" idx="1" style="width:200px;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode">RULEEXECUTABLENAME</div></th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="gridHdr2" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem" idx="2" style="width:200px;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode">SYSTEMTIMESTAMP</div></th></tr></tbody></table></div>
  </div>
 </div></div><table class="dojoxGridFBar" role="presentation" dojoattachevent="onclick:_onClickFilterBar, onmouseenter:_onMouseEnter, onmouseleave:_onMouseLeave, onmousemove:_onMouseMove" id="dojox_grid_enhanced_plugins_filter_FilterBar_0" widgetid="dojox_grid_enhanced_plugins_filter_FilterBar_0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="dojoxGridFBarBtnTD"><span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dojoxGridFBarBtn" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_6" title="Define filter" aria-label="Filter the table"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick" role="presentation"><span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_6_label" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_Button_6" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dojoxGridFBarDefFilterBtnIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">●</span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_6_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">...</span></span></span><input value="" class="dijitOffScreen" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" type="button"></span></td><td class="dojoxGridFBarInfoTD"><span class="dojoxGridFBarInner"><span class="dojoxGridFBarStatus" dojoattachpoint="statusBarNode">No filter applied</span><span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dojoxGridFBarClearFilterBtn" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_7" style="display: none;" aria-label="Clear the filter"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick" role="presentation"><span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_7_label" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_Button_7" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dojoxGridFBarClearFilterBtnIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">●</span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_7_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Clear filter</span></span></span><input value="" class="dijitOffScreen" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" type="button"></span><span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dojoxGridFBarCloseBtn" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_8" style="display: none;"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick" role="presentation"><span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_8_label" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_Button_8" title="Close filter bar" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dojoxGridFBarCloseBtnIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">●</span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone" id="dijit_form_Button_8_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Close filter bar</span></span></span><input value="" class="dijitOffScreen" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" type="button"></span></span></td></tr></tbody></table>
 <div class="dojoxGridMasterView" dojoattachpoint="viewsNode" role="presentation" style="height: 220px;"><div class="dojoxGridView" role="presentation" id="dojox_grid__View_1" widgetid="dojox_grid__View_1" style="width: 679px; left: 1px; top: 0px;">
 
 <input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" dojoattachpoint="hiddenFocusNode" role="presentation" type="checkbox">
 <input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" role="presentation" type="checkbox">
 <div class="dojoxGridScrollbox" dojoattachpoint="scrollboxNode" role="presentation">
  <div class="dojoxGridContent" dojoattachpoint="contentNode" hidefocus="hidefocus" role="presentation" style="height: 220px; width: 679px;"><div role="presentation" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="0" style="width:200px;">Ellen</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:200px;">Sundar</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:200px;">Sarah</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:200px;">Alana</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:200px;">Martha</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="0" style="width:200px;">Eleni</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="0" style="width:200px;">dtfy</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:200px;">dryhy</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:200px;">David</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" style=""><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:200px;">Laura</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:200px;">RuleCheck3</td><td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:200px;">2017-05-09 18:27:11.0</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
 </div>
</div></div>
 <div class="dojoxGridMasterMessages" style="display: none;" dojoattachpoint="messagesNode"></div>
 <span dojoattachpoint="lastFocusNode" tabindex="0"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 canSort : function(index){
        alert(index);
    }
```

is used to prevent column(s) from being sorted for ex: if you have three columns on your grid and for some reason, you don't want one of the column to be sorted then you use this function to limit that. If you want to sort the columns please look into plugin `dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.NestedSorting`

this is how you can restrict column sorting

```
canSort: function(column) { return !(Math.abs(column) === 3); },
```

Here column 3 is restricted for sorting. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, my requirement is not to use nested sort. Can you provide me examples how to restrict or sort particular column use using sort function...

Comment: @Lishanth, this is how you can restrict column sorting                                                      canSort: function(column) {
        return !(Math.abs(column) === 3);
    },                                                                                                                                     Here column 3 is restricted for sorting. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @ Manjunatha Muniyappa for your help...Based on you comments, I changed according to my requirement. It worked fine...

Comment: @Lishanth, Good to see that it helped you. I have updated the answer can you please accept it as the answer?